# Hoisting behavior of `let` in javascript

Tags: javascript, babeljs, hoisting

In the MDN docs on block-scoped variable declarations, `let` is said to not hoist. However, in babel, it seems to do just that in this example [link to babel repl](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=%0Aconst%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20prop%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20test()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this%3A%3Alog()%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20log%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%20console.log(this)%20%7D%3B%0Aobj.test()%3B%0A)...

```
const obj = {
  prop: 1,
  test() {
    this::log();
  }
}

let log = function() { console.log(this) };
obj.test(); // logs "{ prop: 1 }" with no reference error.
```

Am I misunderstanding something about hoisting / the temporal deadzone?

**EDIT**:

Looks like this actually is not an error, as by the time `obj.test()` is called, `log` has been initialized, and is no longer in the temporal deadzone, therefore the reference will resolve and there will be no error. This code runs fine in chrome (`46.0.2490.80`) for example...

```
(function() { 
  'use strict'; 
  let obj = { 
    prop: 1, 
    test: function() { 
      log.call(this);
    } 
  }; 

  let log = function() { 
    console.log(this); 
  }; 
  obj.test(); 
})()
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug in babel. You should open a ticket on their repo. This behavior does seem inconsistent with the browser's native behavior.

Comment: In _ES5_ we don't have `let`, so the `let log` becomes `var log`, the `var` gets hoisted and is therefore referenceable early in the compiled code

Comment: @PaulS. That can be dealt around with the use of adding scopes and the such. The question is whether it's worth it or not (which is really up to the maintainers of babel to decide)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha good idea, I just opened a ticket!

Comment: You can try `let` in an environment with native `let` support, Chrome for example, without Babel. `let` won't get hoisted there.

Comment: I'm sure this would be a _won't fix_ because of the added overhead of scopeing so much but maybe you could convince them to add a _warning in console_

Comment: `let` *does* get hoisted. Given that you are not calling the `test` method before you initialise `log`, you don't run into the *temporal* dead zone.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: No, it's not a bug, it's expected behaviour.

Comment: @Bergi How is it expected? When run by a browser supporting let, it triggers an error.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: Which browser are you testing this in? Works flawlessly in Chrome (with `::` replaced by `call` of course). You can even turn on "high compliancy" in the Babel REPL which enables TDZ and it still runs.

Comment: @Bergi You are correct. My bad.